# timestamp countdown in javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need some help to code a script that counts down the days, hours, minutes and seconds from a unix timestamp.

timestamp is created with php

```
<? php echo hours ();?>
```

And I want the script to count down in real time with JavaScript.

**Example**
2 days, 3:15:39

Hope someone can help me a little:)

Comment: What, precisely, does `<? php echo hours ();?>` write into the document that javascript is supposed use for the count down? e.g is it seconds since the UNIX epoch? The number of seconds/minutes/hours whatever to count down? The time to count down to? What?

Answer (score 10):

First you have some PHP errors. It should be e.g.

```
<?php echo time(); ?>
```

I'm using a timestamp in JavaScript for the ease of showing an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/AvXd3/

```
// the difference timestamp
var timestamp = (Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 3) - Date.now();

timestamp /= 1000; // from ms to seconds

function component(x, v) {
    return Math.floor(x / v);
}

var $div = $('div');

setInterval(function() { // execute code each second

    timestamp--; // decrement timestamp with one second each second

    var days    = component(timestamp, 24 * 60 * 60),      // calculate days from timestamp
        hours   = component(timestamp,      60 * 60) % 24, // hours
        minutes = component(timestamp,           60) % 60, // minutes
        seconds = component(timestamp,            1) % 60; // seconds

    $div.html(days + " days, " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds); // display

}, 1000); // interval each second = 1000 ms
```

Comment: *setInterval* will not run at exactly the specified interval and will slowly drift, so it will become out of sync with the system clock and occasionally skip two seconds. Much better to call *setTimeout*, calculating the time to about 20ms past the next full second. It may still skip, but only if the system is busy, not because of drift, and will mostly "tick" in sync with the system clock.

Answer (score 0):

I just refactored the code above

```js
var limitDays = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 //"24 hours"
var days = 365
var expired = false

var currentTime = new Date()
console.log("set var [ now ] with this: ", currentTime.valueOf())
console.log("set var [ validity ] with this: ", createValidity())

function createValidity() {
    return days * limitDays
}

function component(x, v) {
    return Math.floor(x / v);
}

function getTimer(timestamp) {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        timestamp -= 1000
        var days = component(timestamp / 1000, 24 * 60 * 60),
            hours = component(timestamp / 1000, 60 * 60) % 24,
            minutes = component(timestamp / 1000, 60) % 60,
            seconds = component(timestamp / 1000, 1) % 60;

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = (days + " days " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes " + seconds + " seconds")

        if (timestamp < 0) {
            console.log("expired")
            clearInterval(interval)
            getTimer(createValidity())
        }
    }, 1000)
}

var validity = 31536000000
var now = 1711578707493
var converter = (validity - (currentTime.valueOf() - now))
getTimer(converter)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
    </head>
    <body> 
    <div id="countdown"></div>  
  </body>
</html>
```