# Javascript countdown and PHP date

Tags: php, javascript, date, countdown

Here is a JavaScript that I use to generate some countdowns, my problem is that the JavaScript is using the date from the users PC, is there any way to modify the script to use something like :

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('Ireland/Dublin');
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s A', time());?>
```

Here is the current code used on the site to display multiple countdown on the page.

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">//<![CDATA[


<?php
    echo 'StartCountDown("c' . $post->ID . '","' . $enddate . '")';

    ?>


  function StartCountDown(myDiv,myTargetDate)
  {
    var dthen   = new Date(myTargetDate);
    var dnow    = new Date();
    ddiff       = new Date(dthen-dnow);
    gsecs       = Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf()/1000);
    CountBack(myDiv,gsecs);
  }

  function Calcage(secs, num1, num2)
  {
    s = ((Math.floor(secs/num1))%num2).toString();
    if (s.length < 2) 
    {   
      s = "0" + s;
    }
    return (s);
  }

  function CountBack(myDiv, secs)
  {
    var DisplayStr;
    var DisplayFormat = "%%D%% %%H%%:%%M%%:%%S%%";
    DisplayStr = DisplayFormat.replace(/%%D%%/g,    Calcage(secs,86400,100000));
    DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g,       Calcage(secs,3600,24));
    DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%M%%/g,       Calcage(secs,60,60));
    DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%S%%/g,       Calcage(secs,1,60));
    if(secs > 0)
    {   
      document.getElementById(myDiv).innerHTML = DisplayStr;
      setTimeout("CountBack('" + myDiv + "'," + (secs-1) + ");", 990);
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById(myDiv).innerHTML = "&nbsp;SOLD OUT";
    }
  }

//]]></script>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like its as simple as changing

```
var dnow    = new Date();
```

to something like:

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('Ireland/Dublin'); ?>
var dnow    = new Date( <?= time(); ?>);
```

Comment: There is no date format - It is up to the JS to determine how it wants to output the date and what format it is done in. This solution uses [time](http://www.php.net/time), which returns a UNIX timestamp to set the JS `Date` object to the server time.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981838/timestamp-countdown-in-javascript-and-php) here on SO, the snippet written by @pimvdb is really good and really readable. Very straightforward to modify aswell.

Comment: no no really that easy, perhaps you can come with an example - I have no idea of Javascript